# Silverlight3: DataGrid vertical scrollbar missing when binding to PagedCollectionView

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I have a Silverlight DataGrid and I have set the ItemsSource to an instance of PagedCollectionView (I'm wanting to paginate my data with DataPagers).

I've noticed that the vertical scrollbar disappears when using the PagedCollectionView - which is a problem for me because I have the DataGrid nested inside of a Grid in which the RowDefinition.Height is set to Auto (I want my DataGrid to be as big as possible).  Now the DataGrid extends beyond the window. I still don't see the Scrollbar when I set VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" on my DataGrid - just a gray strip where it should be.

Does anyone know how I can use PagedCollectionView without having to explicitly specify the height of the DataGrid?

EDIT:
Woops - this was my fault.  I can't remember what I did wrong (I figured out my problem a week or two ago), but it had something to do with me not paying attention to the surrounding layout.

Thanks,
-Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nearly always related to the container of the grid rather than the grid itself. A real pain. There are lots of good references for understanding and refreshing your knowledge on the layout system:

- http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?query=silverlight+layout
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025(VS.95).aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-2-using-layout-management.aspx
- http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Layout-Panels-1.aspx